# PulsEffects not saving settings on startup

Tags: pulseaudio

Ever since I've upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 for some reason PulseEffects does not save my settings. Before I applied a preset on the equalizer and it just saved on the system and I never had to do it again whereas now every time the system starts up I have to go and untick and tick the preset for it to work again.

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This bug was reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/1948882) and in a GitHub [thread](https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects/issues/1644). Try the solution described there or upgrade to the [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects) package.

If you are interested in some presets I recommend [these](https://github.com/p-chan5/EasyPulse).