# How to save preset on Pulseeffects Ubuntu

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04

Is there a way to just change something in pulse effects and just save it forever so that everytime PC starts up it loads up with the preset cause its annoying that I have to go to pulse effect every time and change it to the preset again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PulsEffects not saving settings on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429037/pulseffects-not-saving-settings-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 22.04 then you are experiencing [this](https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects/issues/1644) error.

Upgrade to the [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects) version or try the solution described in that thread.

If you need some presets I recommend [these](https://github.com/p-chan5/EasyPulse).

Comment: Hi - it's better if you can to write up or summarize the solution here rather than link to 3rd party sites. Those sites might go down and render your answer useless.